# Why would declaring variables as volatile speed up code execution?

Tags: volatile

Any ideas?  I'm using the GCC cross-compiler for a PPC750.  Doing a simple multiply operation of two floating-point numbers in a loop and timing it.  I declared the variables to be volatile to make sure nothing important was optimized out, and the code sped up!

I've inspected the assembly instructions for both cases and, sure enough, the compiler generated many more instructions to do the same basic job in the non-volatile case.  Execution time for 10,000,000 iterations dropped from 800ms to 300ms!

assembly for volatile case:

```
0x10eeec  stwu  r1,-32(r1)
0x10eef0  lis   r9,0x1d # 29
0x10eef4  lis   r11,0x4080 # 16512
0x10eef8  lfs   fr0,-18944(r9)
0x10eefc  li    r0,0x0 # 0
0x10ef00  lis   r9,0x98 # 152
0x10ef04  stfs  fr0,8(r1)
0x10ef08  mtspr CTR,r9
0x10ef0c  stw   r11,12(r1)
0x10ef10  stw   r0,16(r1)
0x10ef14  ori   r9,r9,0x9680
0x10ef18  mtspr CTR,r9
0x10ef1c  lfs   fr0,8(r1)
0x10ef20  lfs   fr13,12(r1)
0x10ef24  fmuls fr0,fr0,fr13
0x10ef28  stfs  fr0,16(r1)
0x10ef2c  bc    0x10,0, 0x10ef1c # 0x0010ef1c
0x10ef30  addi  r1,r1,0x20 # 32
```

asssembly for non-volatile case:

```
0x10ef04  stwu        r1,-48(r1)
0x10ef08  stw         r31,44(r1)
0x10ef0c  or          r31,r1,r1
0x10ef10  lis         r9,0x1d # 29
0x10ef14  lfs         fr0,-18832(r9)
0x10ef18  stfs        fr0,12(r31)
0x10ef1c  lis         r0,0x4080 # 16512
0x10ef20  stw         r0,16(r31)
0x10ef24  li          r0,0x0 # 0
0x10ef28  stw         r0,20(r31)
0x10ef2c  li          r0,0x0 # 0
0x10ef30  stw         r0,8(r31)
0x10ef34  lwz         r0,8(r31)
0x10ef38  lis         r9,0x98 # 152
0x10ef3c  ori         r9,r9,0x967f
0x10ef40  cmpl        crf0,0,r0,r9
0x10ef44  bc          0x4,1, 0x10ef4c # 0x0010ef4c
0x10ef48  b           0x10ef6c # 0x0010ef6c
0x10ef4c  lfs         fr0,12(r31)
0x10ef50  lfs         fr13,16(r31)
0x10ef54  fmuls       fr0,fr0,fr13
0x10ef58  stfs        fr0,20(r31)
0x10ef5c  lwz         r9,8(r31)
0x10ef60  addi        r0,r9,0x1 # 1
0x10ef64  stw         r0,8(r31)
0x10ef68  b           0x10ef34 # 0x0010ef34
0x10ef6c  lwz         r11,0(r1)
0x10ef70  lwz         r31,-4(r11)
0x10ef74  or          r1,r11,r11
0x10ef78  blr
```

If I read this correctly, it's loading the values from memory during every iteration **in both cases**, but it seems to have generated a lot more instructions to do so in the non-volatile case.

Here's the source:

```
void floatTest()
{
    unsigned long i;
    volatile double d1 = 500.234, d2 = 4.000001, d3=0;
    for(i=0; i<10000000; i++)
        d3 = d1*d2;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the assembly?  Once we see what is left out it may be easier to figure out why?

Comment: I'll try to post the assembly code tomorrow when I'm back in the office.

Comment: Source code may be useful too. Remember to format it correctly by indenting with four spaces. (The editing pane makes this easy todo post-paste)

Comment: ok, got the assembly in there so it's readable.  I'll put the source in also.

Comment: Which optimization level did you compile at?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you didn't also change optimization settings?

The original looks un-optimized - here's the looping part:

```
0x10ef34  lwz         r0,8(r31)       //Put 'i' in r0.
0x10ef38  lis         r9,0x98 # 152   //Put MSB of 10000000 in r9
0x10ef3c  ori         r9,r9,0x967f    //Put LSB of 10000000 in r9
0x10ef40  cmpl        crf0,0,r0,r9    //compare r0 to r9

0x10ef44  bc          0x4,1, 0x10ef4c //branch to loop if r0<r9
0x10ef48  b           0x10ef6c        //else branch to end

0x10ef4c  lfs         fr0,12(r31)     //load d1
0x10ef50  lfs         fr13,16(r31)    //load d2
0x10ef54  fmuls       fr0,fr0,fr13    //multiply
0x10ef58  stfs        fr0,20(r31)     //save d3

0x10ef5c  lwz         r9,8(r31)       //load i into r9
0x10ef60  addi        r0,r9,0x1       //add 1
0x10ef64  stw         r0,8(r31)       //save i

0x10ef68  b           0x10ef34        //go back to top, must reload r9
```

The volatile version looks quite optimized - It rearanges instructions, and  uses the special purpose counter register instead of storing `i` on the stack:

```
0x10ef00  lis   r9,0x98 # 152      //MSB of 10M
//.. 4 initialization instructions here ..
0x10ef14  ori   r9,r9,0x9680       //LSB of 10,000000
0x10ef18  mtspr CTR,r9             // store r9 in Special Purpose CTR register
0x10ef1c  lfs   fr0,8(r1)          // load d1
0x10ef20  lfs   fr13,12(r1)        // load d2
0x10ef24  fmuls fr0,fr0,fr13       // multiply
0x10ef28  stfs  fr0,16(r1)         // store result
0x10ef2c  bc    0x10,0, 0x10ef1c   // decrement counter and branch if not 0.
```

The CTR optimization reduces the loop to 5 instructions, instead of the 14 in the original code.   I don't see any reason 'volatile' by itself would enable that optimization.

Comment: I'll do it again, making sure to not change optimization levels, and see if I get the same thing.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: any luck figuring this one out, @Mike?